# Why can I use the constructor without an object declaration?

Tags: c++, constructor

Why can I use the constructor without a previous object declaration? And, if the previous works, why do I get an error when using k()?
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
int i, x;
public:
Test(int ii = 0)
{
    cout<<"WOW!";
    cout<<i<<" ";

    i=ii;
}
void k()
{
    cout<<i<<" ";
}
};

int main()
{
    Test();
    k();    ///k was not declared in this scope

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You can create temporary objects that don't have names.  And why would you expect to call `k` without an object (the one on the previous line is destroyed by the time you try calling `k`).

Comment: `Test();` in `main` creates a temporary object of type `Test` and immediately destroys it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can I use the constructor without a previous object declaration?

A constructor is used to *create* a new object.  So it can't be called on a previous object.

> And, if the previous works, why do I get an error when using k()?

Because `k()` is a *non-static* method of `Test`, so it needs a `Test` object to call it on.  You can't call it as a standalone function.

```
int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.k();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are constructors static functions?

Comment: @star_man96 no, they are not.  Have a look at [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)

Answer (score 0):

You can create instance of the class because the name of the class can be found with name lookup from the current (the global in this case) namespace, and the class has been defined.

You haven't declared a free function by the name `k`, so you cannot call such function.